# Natural basis and dual basis of a circular paraboloid

Tags: homework-and-exercises, differential-geometry, tensor-calculus, coordinate-systems

I'm trying to obtain the natural and dual basis of a circular paraboloid parametrized by:

$$
x = \sqrt U \cos(V) 
$$

$$
y = \sqrt U \sin(V) 
$$

$$
z = U 
$$

with the inverse relationship:

$$
V = \arctan \frac{y}{x} 
$$

$$
U = z 
$$

The natural basis is:

$$
e_U = \frac{\partial \overrightarrow{r}} {\partial U }=\frac{\partial x} {\partial U }\hat {i} + \frac{\partial y} {\partial U }\hat {j} + \frac{\partial z} {\partial U }\hat {k}=
$$

$$
 = \frac {\cos(V)}{2\sqrt{U}} \hat {i} + \frac {\sin(V)}{2\sqrt{U}} \hat {j} + \hat {k}
$$

$$
e_V = \frac{\partial \overrightarrow{r}} {\partial V }=\frac{\partial x} {\partial V }\hat {i} + \frac{\partial y} {\partial V }\hat {j} + \frac{\partial z} {\partial V }\hat {k}=
$$

$$
 = -\sqrt{U} \sin(V) \hat {i} + \sqrt{U} \cos(V) \hat {j} + 0\hat {k}
$$

Which gives the following metric tensor:

$$
e_U\cdot e_U=g_{UU}=1+\frac{1}{4U}
$$

$$
e_U\cdot e_V=g_{UV}=g_{VU}=0
$$

$$
e_V\cdot e_V=g_{VV}=U
$$

What respects to the dual basis:

$$
e^U = \nabla U=\frac{\partial U} {\partial x }\hat {i} + \frac{\partial U} {\partial y }\hat {j} + \frac{\partial U} {\partial z }\hat {k}=
$$

$$
 = 0\hat {i} + 0\hat {j} + \hat {k}
$$

$$
e^V = \nabla V=\frac{\partial V} {\partial x }\hat {i} + \frac{\partial V} {\partial y }\hat {j} + \frac{\partial V} {\partial z }\hat {k}=
$$

$$
 = \frac{-y}{x^2+y^2}\hat {i} + \frac{x}{x^2+y^2}\hat {j} + 0\hat {k}=-\frac{\sqrt{U}\sin(V)}{U}\hat {i} + \frac{\sqrt{U}\cos(V)}{U}\hat {j} + 0\hat {k}
$$

However, in this case, the metric tensor is:

$$
e^U\cdot e^U=g^{UU}=1
$$

$$
e^U\cdot e^V=g^{UV}=g^{VU}=0
$$

$$
e^V\cdot e^V=g^{VV}=\frac{1}{U}
$$

which is definitely not the inverse of the one I obtained from the natural basis, because the component $$g^{UU}$$ should be $$\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{4U}}$$ and not 1 (The metric tensor is diagonal)

Could anyone tell me where am I wrong?

Comment: Welcome to Physics! Welcome to Physics! Please note that this is not a homework help site. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/25301) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems.](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093/25301)